# Can you output a HTML table in PHP by using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

By using AJAX, the objective is to grab "table" information through an external class that is PHP.

**AJAX Request**

```
<script>
            
    function fetch_select(val){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../assets/includes/class_finder.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {option:val},
            dataType: 'html',
            success:function(result){
                $("#result").html(result);
            }
        });
    } 
           
</script>
```

**PHP File** (class_finder.php)

```
<?php

    $varValue1 = "Value 1";
    $varValue2 = "Value 2";

    echo "<tr><td><div class='team'>$varValue1</div></td>
        <td>
            <div class='text-center'>
                <p class='text-dark' style='padding-top:15px;'>$varValue2</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>";

?>
```

**HTML Result**:
[image: HTML Result from AJAX Request]

What can be changed to have an output of table data in HTML through AJAX?

Comment: can you share the #result html code

Comment: Missing `<tr>` tag . Between what doesn't work ? Are you getting reponse back from php or not ? Try printing them i.e : `console.log(result)`

Comment: @Swati I am receiving a response back, however it is not completing the remainder of my table.

Comment: Read up PHP REST API and Fetch API. You'll be returning a JSON response to your browser and filling in the table client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was sending an XMLHTTP request from the HTML file to the PHP file.

**AJAX Request**

```
function ajaxFunction(str) {
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../assets/includes/class_finder.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting response from server side then you can do following:

```
<script>            
    function fetch_select(val){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../assets/includes/class_finder.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {option:val},
            dataType: 'html',
            success:function(result){
                // Here result is id of table tag
                $("#result").html(result);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }            
</script>
```

PHP File (class_finder.php)

```
<?php
    $varValue1 = "Value 1";
    $varValue2 = "Value 2";
    $varValue3 = "Value 3";
    echo "<tr>
            <td>
                <div class='team'>$varValue1</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class='text-center'>
                    <p class='text-dark' style='padding-top:15px;'>$varValue2</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>";
?>
```